# Why I can't update my data in my database with jquery using post request?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to update some data into my database using Jquery, but nothing is happening.

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="container form-control text-center">

ID : <input type="text" name="id_user" id="id_user" value="<?= $userInfo['id_user']; ?>" class="form-control" disabled></input><br>
<input type="text" id="notification" name="notification" class="form-control" placeholder="Écrivez une notification..."></input><br>


<input type="submit" class="publishNotif" value="publish">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$('.publishNotif').click(function(){

    var notification = $("#notification").val();

    $.post("publishNotifRequest.php", {
        notification: notification,
        id_user: id_user
    });

});
```

in the file called "publishNotifRequest.php" :

```
if(isset($_POST['notification']) AND !empty($_POST['notification']) AND isset($_POST['id_user']) AND !empty($_POST['id_user'])){

$insertNotif = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE USERS SET notification = :notification WHERE id_user = :id_user');

$insertNotif->execute(array(
    "notification" => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['notification'])), // trim supprime les espaces debut et fin de chaine
    "id_user"
));
```

}

Comment: Well for one thing, your click event for the submit button is not being cancelled.  So most likely the form will submit before the ajax finishes running.

Comment: This is overly complicated `if(isset($_POST['notification']) AND !empty($_POST['notification']) AND isset($_POST['id_user']) AND !empty($_POST['id_user'])){` you can just do `if(!empty($_POST['notification']) && !empty($_POST['id_user'])){` instead.  Empty treats unset/undefined variables as being empty, with no errors.

Comment: Also in your `$insertNotif->execute(array(`  your missing the value for the key `"id_user"`, so this just becomes a string in the array.

Comment: I would only use `htmlspecialchars` for outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the other comments and my own observations:

In JS

```
$('.publishNotif').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    // --- add this
    var notification = $("#notification").val();

    $.post("publishNotifRequest.php", {
        notification: notification,
        id_user: id_user
    });
});
```

In PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['notification']) AND !empty($_POST['notification']) AND isset($_POST['id_user']) AND !empty($_POST['id_user'])){

    $insertNotif = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE USERS SET notification = :notification WHERE id_user = :id_user');

    $insertNotif->execute(array(
        "notification" => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['notification'])), 
        "id_user"      => $_POST['id_user']  // --- add this
    ));

}
```

Also note the comments, which show the changes I made.  The biggest issue you had that I saw was this:

```
$insertNotif->execute(array(
    "notification" => trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['notification'])), // trim supprime les espaces debut et fin de chaine
    "id_user"  //<<----- no value for this "key"
));
```

Because you just had `"id_user"` in there, PHP will make that a string literal (element in the array) and not a key for your array.  Then because this is the ID you need to update your DB, it can't find the row to update because there is no ID in there that is `"id_user"`.  That's assuming of course that PDO (which is what it looks like) would let you do that, which it wont as the keys are not correctly matched to the placeholders in your Query.

If you looked at the return of your request or the error logs, you would probably see something like `PDOException - wrong number of parameters supplied` etc. for `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Also as @Taplar mentioned in the comments, in your JS you need to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button.  We can do that with `e.preventDefault()` assuming we set an argument for the `e` variable or `event` (but I'm to lazy to type that out).

Hope it works out for you...

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Taplar said in comment, your click event for the submit button is not being cancelled. So most likely the form will submit before the ajax finishes running, I suggest you to use the equivalent form to send the request asynchronously by setting `async: false`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: publishNotifRequest.php,
  notification: notification,
  id_user: id_user
});
```